# Display User Name in Users Field in CP

Tags: users

Is there a way to do this? Emails are pretty ugly when selecting people.

I'm guessing it would be a quick plugin to write, if I wrote plugins. Anyone done this before?

Answer (score 1):

The [Users field](https://craftcms.com/docs/users-fields) uses the username for the display label by default when showing what users have been selected.

My guess is you've got the [useEmailAsUsername](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#useEmailAsUsername) config setting set to `true`?

Comment: I have the same problem. I could see changing the username field by hand, but I guess this field is not even displayed when useEmailAsUsername is set to true?  Ideally you could choose wich field to display when adding a users field.